# ColdFusion datasource error: can't connect to database login failed

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, dsn

I keep getting the same error:  Connection verification failed for data source: estimates
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Cannot open database "estimates" requested by the login. The login failed.

I have checked in Sql Server Configuration Manager and TCP/IP is enabled in all of the SQL Server settings, and I'm using Windows Authentication only to access the SQL Server DB on my local server.

Can someone help fix this so I can set up a DSN, please?  Thank you!

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log. It should have more specifics on the reason for the login failed.

Comment: Have you given ColdFusion a Windows account?

Answer (score 0):

Likely a SQL configuration issue.   Once you add the Login to the server, go back to the database and add the user to it.  You'll need to add a role, as well, usually dbo for simplicity, but not necessarily security.

If you've restored the database from another source, you might need to run this command:

```
USE [yourdb]
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'theLoginName'
```

Comment: How do I add the Login to the server?

Comment: This is more of a Microsoft SQL Question, but you use the SQL Studio:
https://www.guru99.com/sql-server-create-user.html

Comment: I am not able to log in with user 'sa' because it's disabled.    Enable Login. failed for Login 'sa'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)  Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15151)

Comment: In the error log, I found this.  Does this mean anything to anyone?  2022-07-24 07:38:12.80 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/DESKTOP-94SV1LK ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63. Failure to register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually registered.

Comment: You might take these issues to the SQL Server area:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server

Comment: Thanks, Will.  I will look for a SQL server specific forum.

Comment: I did add a user and gave it all permissions, but I still can't connect.  I might have to try a ColdFusion or Dreamweaver specific forum.  Thank you.